# Is there a more pythonic way to write this script? I want to develop good habits as I learn the language

Tags: python, methods, boolean

Answered - Final Product:

```
from sys import argv

try:
    with open(argv[1],"r") as file:
        contentcount = sum(1 for line in file 
                    if (stripstart := line.strip()) 
                    and not stripstart.startswith("#"))
        print(f"Total lines of code: {contentcount}")
except FileNotFoundError:
    print(f"{argv[1]} doesn't exist")
finally:
    file.close()
```

Items changed:

- Removed the use of lists to avoid memory issues for larger files
- Removed duplicate lists
- Specified missing file name in exception handling
- Explicit file closure in case `while open` runs into a problem and fails to close file
- Replaced logic to instead check each line for `string not empty`, `and not` starting with #.
- Ensured the logic does not improperly reject unexpected characters, since we only want to reject comments and blank lines, now only checking for # and "".

---

Original question:

This function grabs a file name written on command line, then prints the file's code line count, ignoring comments and empty lines.

```
from sys import argv

try:
    with open(argv[1],"r") as file:
        content = [line.strip() for line in file.readlines() if line.strip()!=""] #stores all char lines as strings

        i=0
        for line in content:
            if line[0].isalnum():
                i += 1
            else:
                continue

        print(f"Total lines of code: {i}")

except FileNotFoundError:
    print("that file doesn't exist")
```

It functions as expected, though I'm unsure if my use of a longer list comprehension is good practice here, especially with all the string methods I crammed into there.

I have tried putting the empty string check into the bool block, but it seemed less-readable, and I want to work on relying less on bool loops.

Comment: For fully working code you're looking for style tips on, I'd recommend the [Code Review Stack Exchange site](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: The list comprehension seems like a waste.  You don't NEED the whole file in memory.  Just do `for line in file:`.  `isalnum` is not a reliable comment detector, depending on the language.  Perhaps you should look for '#' or '//' specifically.

Comment: The `try/except` is useless.  You're not doing anything special to handle the exception, so you might as well just let the exception happen naturally.  It might contain some details that help you diagnose the problem.

Comment: @JohnGordon: In a utility function, I'd agree. If it's a top level script like this, `FileNotFoundError` is tightly scoped enough that the user-friendly summary rather than dumping a full traceback to screen is reasonable. You could add the missing file name for clarity, but everything else is meaningless to the user in production code.

Comment: Alternate to Tim Roberts comment: if you really prefer to separate the `content=` computation, and then the iteration over it (`for line in content`), at least, make it an generator. `content=(line.strip() for line in file.readlines() if line.strip()!="")` with parenthesis not brackets. Then you can `for line in content` as you already do. The difference is that `line` is computed, one by one, while you are iterating, without the unnecessary memory waste of reading everything in a list

Comment: Also, consider cases of line of code `_x=12`, counted as comment, when they are code.  Or lines starting with letters, but enclosed between `'''`. Counted as code when they are comment (well, one may say that it is not really comment, but a void string. Exactly like a line `'comment'` is. But well, it is used as comment)

Comment: @chrslg: `.readlines()` is already "unnecessary memory waste of reading everything into a list", so you'd want to drop it; files are iterables of their lines, `.readlines()` is thoroughly useless (it's *exactly* equivalent to a lightly optimized version of `list(file)`).

Comment: Thank you everyone! I am looking at the code review website now, revisiting my list comprehension, the unnecessary else:continue, and the lists. I wasn't aware that a file already exists as iterable by line.

Comment: Adding onto what others have mentioned, it is often best to keep file interaction to a minimum. That is, the file is open by python within the entire `with open...` block. If all you need to do is read the contents of the file, do that, and then exit the `with open` block to continue further operations. This is minor, but can prevent potential file locking issues, file corruption and unnecessary resource usage.

Comment: @ShadowRanger oh, yes, right. I dealt with only one useless list. So `content=(line.strip() for line in file if line.strip()!="")` then.

Comment: I think you should not be afraid of raising exceptions. Let the `open` raise `FileNotFoundError`. Only printing `that file doesn't exist` may look cleaner, but it lacks traceback information. And both express the same thing: `File Does Not Exist`

Comment: I'm working on implementing these suggestions now, could you describe what is meant by missing traceback information? Perhaps the non-specificity, such as WHICH file is missing?

Comment: @tron359 yes. Python interpreter will print out, on which file and line, due to which error an exception is raised. So that's a lot of information you are missing.

Comment: @MSH I have added `print(f"{argv[1]} doesn't exist")`, would this resolve your concern?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Improvements:

1. Don't make a `list` if you don't need one (you make two, one with the unnecessary `.readlines()` call, another with the listcomp itself)
2. Empty strings are falsy, no need to compare them to the empty string
3. You can use the walrus operator (`:=`, aka the assignment expression) to avoid `strip`ing twice
4. `else: continue` is pointless when the `if` is controlling all the other code in the loop anyway
5. If your work can be done cleanly in a generator expression, `sum` can consume it to tally the results quickly with minimal memory overhead

Shortened code:

```
from sys import argv

try:
    with open(argv[1],"r") as file:
        i = sum(1 for line in file
                  if (stripped := line.strip()) and stripped.isalnum())
        print(f"Total lines of code: {i}")
except FileNotFoundError:
    print("that file doesn't exist")
```

That involves *zero* temporary `list`s (so it works on files of any size as long as any given *line* doesn't exceed your available memory), and should run moderately faster as a bonus.

Technically, you could just use: `i = sum(1 for line in file if line.strip().isalnum())` because the empty string is not considered alphanumeric, but that's not an entirely obvious edge case and it does involve an extra method call that could be avoided for empty strings, so it's reasonable to split it up into testing the stripped form for truthiness, then testing for alphanumeric content.

As a note: You say you're ignoring comments, but you're actually ignoring any line that's not purely alphanumeric after removing leading and trailing whitespace. If you're only trying to exclude Python comment lines, change `stripped.isalnum()` to `not stripped.startswith('#')` to narrow the types of lines excluded to comment lines alone. You couldn't use the condensed test from the prior paragraph though, since the empty string would not start with `'#'` and would pass the second test if the first one was skipped.

Comment: I like your method of summation, especially since it doesn't rely on creating i in a separate line. I also note the splitting of the generator into 2 lines for readability, handy. Seeing that it directly looks for an nonempty line string after stripping, and checks alnum, more elegant than mine.

Comment: Rather than using the walrus operator, you might: `i = sum(1 for line in file for stripped in (line.strip(),) if stripped.isalnum())`

Comment: I have created a modified version (because I don't want to copy paste, and I feel like I understand better if I try creating alternative versions) in the form of: 
`count = sum(1 for line in file if (stripstart := line.strip()) and not stripstart.startswith("#"))`

Comment: @Chris: Yeah, they optimized that construct to allow people to avoid the walrus's behavior of leaking the assignment outside the genexpr/listcomp (it works with an anonymous `list` too, so you could avoid the ugly trailing comma). It still feels ugly to me, but then, the walrus ain't exactly beautiful either.

Answer (score 0):

A couple suggestions, not necessarily "pythonic" but good to do anyways:

1. Avoid calling `strip()` twice on every line
2. You do not need the explicit `continue` in your loop
3. Make your exception handling tight if possible, i.e. only the file opening bit needs to be in a try block
4. You could use list comprehension instead of your `for` loop, filter the non-alphanumeric items and then look at list length

Comment: The exception handling suggestion is a good one, but it's a little annoying to do with `with` block controlled file opens, and opening the file without a `with` feels... ugly/dangerous. Given the narrowly scoped *type* of exception being handled, it's not a big deal here.

Comment: @ShadowRanger can I ask why exception handling is annoying to do with `with` block controlled file opens? Could op not perform the `with open` in the `try` block, catch the exception if one occurs, and then perform necessary operations on the file contents in the `else` block? I've never tried doing this so I don't know, but I was curious as to why you say it's annoying.

Comment: For suggestion 3, you may want to then suggest that if the try block only surroudnds the file opening and reading the contents, the exception handling will have to explicitly exit the program to avoid running the rest of the program subsequently.

Comment: @jahank: To reach the `else` block, you'd be exiting the `try`, and if the `with` is inside the `try`, you've exited the `with` too. The only way to get around it is the kind of ugly: `try: fil = open(...)`, `except FileNotFoundError: ...`, then doing `with file:` immediately after.

Comment: @ShadowRanger sorry I still don't follow. If the `else` block is reached, then the `try` has exited without exception. That means the `with` has run without issue and supposedly the file contents have been extracted as desired - operations can now be performed on the extracted data, and we don't need to re-enter the `with` block since we have the file contents, we don't need to open the file again. So what problem do we have?

Comment: @jahank: Right, but you can't wrap *just* the `open` call, you have to wrap the `with` block and all its contents, when you're only expecting to catch the exception from the `open`. Razumov was noting that, when possible, you want to minimize the content of the `try` block as much as possible, so you don't potentially catch the same exception raised by an unexpected source (e.g. if some API call led to the `FileNotFoundError` that wasn't from the `open`, it would be handled the same way as if it was from the `open`, leading to a misleading behavior).